# file command + search directories and sub-directories

Tags: file, shell, directory, command, subdirectory

If `file *.txt` gets all text files from the current directory, how can I use it in order to get the text files from a specific directory and all its sub-directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you are looking for

```
$ find . -name '*.txt' -exec file {} +
```